# Can't create file by signed, nortarized, non-sandboxed Mac app

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm developing a signed, notarized, non-sandboxed Mac app which isn't distributed on App Store.

The app successfully runs locally using "Export Notarized App" on Xcode, so I created zip file of the app.

However, after downloading the zip file from Web server and extracting it, the app fails to create log file.

Could you tell me what's happening to the app?